# programmatically querying downloadable files from sourceforge

Tags: rest, sourceforge

sourceforge provides a [RESTfull api](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Allura%20API/) to query certain properties of a project.
E.g. http://sourceforge.net/rest/p/forge

However, I'm missing a way to query all downloadable/released files (or parts thereof) of a project.

I did a wild guess, but that doesn't seem to work (as in `404`): http://sourceforge.net/rest/p/forge/files

So my question is: is there a way to programmatically query downloadable files for a sourceforge project?

### context

I'm currently writing plugin a download manager for an application, where people can query for existing plugins wrt name, architecture,...

Many plugins are available as downloads from sourceforge (with known projects), and I would like to make them available to my users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a rest-API for the task yet, but sf provides an RSS-feed for all the files, which is simple enough to parse:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/forge/rss
```

The feed has a limited number of items, but you can set the limit manually to something ridiculously high::

```
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/forge/rss?limit=10000000000000000000
```